# Redis in docker desktop kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, docker-desktop

I am using helm to install redis in kubernetes:

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm repo update

helm upgrade --install `
--set auth.password=*** `
--set architecture=standalone `
yatp-redis bitnami/redis `
--namespace redis --create-namespace `
```

If I run in a cloud cluster (e.g. aks) no problems. However If the cluster is the one provided by docker desktop (Windows), the container crashes with the following log:

```
1:C 30 May 2023 06:10:57.645 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
1:C 30 May 2023 06:10:57.645 # Redis version=7.0.11, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
1:C 30 May 2023 06:10:57.645 # Configuration loaded
1:M 30 May 2023 06:10:57.645 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
1:M 30 May 2023 06:10:57.646 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
1:M 30 May 2023 06:10:57.646 # Server initialized
1:M 30 May 2023 06:10:57.646 # Can't open or create append-only dir appendonlydir: Permission denied
```

Can someone help?